# Find the difference from two arrays in php

Tags: php

**--$arr1----**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [Name] => AAA
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [Name] => BBB
            )

    )
```

**--$arr2---**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => AAA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [Name] => BBB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [Name] => CCC
        )

)
```

I would like the final result as following. Is there anyone can help me?

**--Final Result--**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [Name] => CCC
        )

)
```

**UPDATE---**

In this case, the result of **array_diff($arr1,$arr2) is empty**.

Comment: in PHP document is wrote: array_diff"This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array"

Comment: There are examples in the comments on the array_diff() page of the php docs of mult-dimensional array versions

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is Mark Baker's solution or just write your own simple function:

### Code:

```
function arrdiff($a1, $a2) {
  $res = array();
  foreach($a2 as $a) if (array_search($a, $a1) === false) $res[] = $a;
  return $res;
  }

print_r(arrdiff($arr1, $arr2));
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [id] => 46
      [name] => CCC
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr1 = array(array('id' => 1,  'Name' => 'AAA'),
              array('id' => 6,  'Name' => 'BBB')
             );

$arr2 = array(array('id' => 1,  'Name' => 'AAA'),
              array('id' => 6,  'Name' => 'BBB'),
              array('id' => 46, 'Name' => 'CCC')
             );
$results = array_diff(array_map('serialize',$arr2),array_map('serialize',$arr1));
$results = array_map('unserialize',$results);

var_dump($results);
```

**EDIT**

And just for the sheer fun of it, you could use array_filter() instead of array_diff() - which means no need to serialize anything at all

```
$results = array_filter($arr2, function ($value) use($arr1) { return !in_array($value,$arr1); } );

var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$finalResult = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

If you need more complex comparison you may also build foreach loop and use like this:

```php
function compareItems( $a, $b){
    return $a['id'] == $b['id']; // Example compare criteria
}

$result = array();
foreach( $arr1 as $item){
    foreach( $arr2 as $key => $it){
        if( !compareItems( $item, $it)){
             $result[] = $it; // Either build new array
             unset( $arr2[$key]); // Or remove items from original array
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

And than you'll probably want to implement the same with reversed order of `$arr1` and `$arr2`.

Comment: I used array_diff($arr1, $arr2); however, the result is empty

Comment: As written by "the frox": http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#98680 (that'll work, cause you're using multi-dimensional arrays)

Comment: @Acubi so try example that I've added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrDif=array();

$i=0;
foreach($arr1 as $value)
{
    if(!in_array($value, $arr2))
    {
        $arrDif[$i]=$value;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Counter `$i` is unnecessary. `$arrDif[]=$value;` should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with array_udiff()

```
function arr_comp($a, $b)
{
   if ($a['id'] == $b['id'])
       return 0;
   else if ($a['id'] > $b['id'])
       return 1;
   else
       return -1;
}

$result = array_udiff($arr2, $arr1, 'arr_comp');
```

or if you don't know in which array the differences may be you can try:

```
$res1 = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, 'arr_comp');
$res2 = array_udiff($arr2, $arr1, 'arr_comp');
$result = array_merge($res1, $res2);
```

Comment: You can simplify the arr_comp function to only test for '==' and even test other parameters as well.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the PHP built-in function [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). That'll help you out :-) Just pass your two arrays, and store the array returned by array_diff(), which will contain the differences between the two arrays.

As you're using multi-dimensional arrays, look at this comment on the PHP website: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#98680.