# PHP Difference of two assoc Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays of assoc arrays:

first one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [24] => s
            [23] => czarny
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [24] => m
            [23] => czarny
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [24] => l
            [23] => czarny
        )

)
```

and second:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [24] => l
            [23] => czarny
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [23] => czarny
            [24] => m
        )

)
```

in output I would like to get:

```
Array
(
      [24] => s
      [23] => czarny
)
```

because two of arrays:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [23] => czarny
            [24] => m
        )
```

and

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [24] => m
            [23] => czarny
        )
```

are the same for me.
Does anyone have idea how to deal with that? I tried to do this which fourth nested foreach but I got confused..

Comment: Those are **not** associative arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the difference from two arrays in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278150/find-the-difference-from-two-arrays-in-php).  This question is exactly the same and already has several answers.

Comment: @Dan None of those do not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little loop crazy, but it will work.

```
$array1[0][23] = 'czarny';
$array1[0][24] = 'm';

$array1[1][23] = 'czarny';
$array1[1][24] = 's';

$array1[2][23] = 'czarny';
$array1[2][24] = 'l';

$array2[0][23] = 'czarny';
$array2[0][24] = 'm';

$array2[1][23] = 'czarny';
$array2[1][24] = 'l';

end($array1);

// Merge two arrays
$array3 =   array_merge($array1,$array2);
// Loop through the one array and create a second assoc array based on key 24
foreach($array1 as $mainKey => $object) {
        foreach($object as $key => $value) {
                $newArray[$object[24]][$key] = $value;
            }
    }
// Loop through new array to create yet another new one but reset keys back to numeric
$i=0;
foreach($newArray as $key => $value) {
        $final[$i]  =   $value;

        $i++;
    }

print_r($final);
```